# Defunct process in AIX

Tags: java, aix

Edited note: FYI, application extensively muti-threaded  based desgined so may be something wrong in code. I need some time to trace code and get back in details.
thanks.

Comment: The Java process keeps running, but is marked as defunct?

Comment: defunct process's PPID/JVM is running but not defunct process but if  I restart JVM then only all defunct processes cleans up.

Comment: JVM doesn't fork of itself, so some Java code must have done something like `Runtime.exec`.